# splitmuxsink doesn't use audio from matroskademux

Tags: audio, gstreamer

I have a following pipeline, that combines video from the camera, and audio from the microphone, and makes two outputs:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v libcamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' ! v4l2convert ! clockoverlay time-format="%A | %d %B %Y | %H:%M:%S" ! v4l2h264enc extra-controls="controls, h264_profile=4, video_bitrate=2000000" ! 'video/x-h264,profile=high,level=(string)4' ! h264parse ! mux. \
alsasrc device=hw:1,0 ! queue ! audioconvert ! lamemp3enc ! mux. \
matroskamux name=mux ! tee name=t \
t. ! queue ! matroskademux ! splitmuxsink location="splitvideo-%02d.mkv" max-size-bytes=100000000 max-files=80 muxer=matroskamux \
t. ! queue ! filesink location=fullvideo.mkv
```

The problem is that the `fullvideo.mkv` has audio, but the `splitvideo-%02d.mkv` files don't have audio. Why is that? It seems that `matroskademux` should provide proper caps that `splitmuxsink` should be able to use, but it ignores them.

**Added:**

I also tried to achieve this in a different way:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v libcamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' ! v4l2convert ! clockoverlay time-format="%A | %d %B %Y | %H:%M:%S" ! v4l2h264enc extra-controls="controls, h264_profile=4, video_bitrate=2000000" ! 'video/x-h264,profile=high,level=(string)4' ! h264parse ! tee name=videoTee \
alsasrc device=hw:1,0 ! queue ! audioconvert ! lamemp3enc ! tee name=audioTee \
splitmuxsink location="%02d.mkv" max-size-bytes=100000000 max-files=80 muxer=matroskamux name=splitVideosMux \
matroskamux name=fullVideoMux ! filesink location=fullvideo.mkv \
audioTee. ! queue ! fullVideoMux. \
videoTee. ! queue ! fullVideoMux. \
audioTee. ! queue ! splitVideosMux. \
videoTee. ! queue ! splitVideosMux.
```

But this ends up with `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link queue3 to splitVideosMux` for some reason. Which doesn't seem to make any sense because it works after simply removing the `queue`:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v libcamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' ! v4l2convert ! clockoverlay time-format="%A | %d %B %Y | %H:%M:%S" ! v4l2h264enc extra-controls="controls, h264_profile=4, video_bitrate=2000000" ! 'video/x-h264,profile=high,level=(string)4' ! h264parse ! tee name=videoTee \
alsasrc device=hw:1,0 ! queue ! audioconvert ! lamemp3enc ! tee name=audioTee \
splitmuxsink location="%02d.mkv" max-size-bytes=100000000 max-files=80 muxer=matroskamux name=splitVideosMux \
matroskamux name=fullVideoMux ! filesink location=fullvideo.mkv \
audioTee. ! queue ! fullVideoMux. \
videoTee. ! queue ! fullVideoMux. \
audioTee. ! splitVideosMux. \
videoTee. ! splitVideosMux.
```

^ So, this is my actually working solution for now, but it seems faulty because there should be queues behind the tees.

There is something going on with `splitmuxsink` that I don't understand. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In your first pipeline you make one connection from the demux to the new mux. That will connect the first viable pad between the two. That seems to be video then. Make another connection to connect the second pad (audio) too.